# Laravel: How to broadcast to a random queue name?

Tags: php, laravel

so I'd like to see how I can broadcast messages using Laravel Broadcasting but to a random queue.

So I've got a Broadcasting event that looks like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class ChannelUpdated implements ShouldBroadcast {
    
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $id, $data;

    public function __construct($id, $data) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function broadcastOn() {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-'.$this->id);
    }
}
```

Now I know that you can add `public $queue = 'queue name';` to the event itself and it will broadcast to a specific queue on the default connection. But I'd like to be able to RANDOMLY set the queue for performance reasons.

So how can I have an array of queue names and then once this event is loaded it selects ONE queue name from the array, randomly, and broadcasts to that queue.

Thank you!

Comment: You can implement `viaQueue` as a function on the event and write code in there to select a random channel [(docs)](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/events#customizing-the-queue-connection-queue-name)

Comment: Thank you so much - i'll try this out and let you know.